# Having trouble creating a bitmap image; fileheader/infoheader is wrong

Tags: c++, image, bitmap

I am trying to create a 24-bitmap image from an image captured by a high powered camera (Allied Vision Technologies Prosilica  GT2750).  Here is what I have so far: (note the VmbUInt32 is defined as " typedef unsigned __int32    VmbUint32_t;" and VmbUchar_t is just an unsigned char)

```
        VmbUint32_t imageSize = 0;
        pFrame->GetImageSize(imageSize); //imageSize = 6054400

        VmbUint32_t imageWidth = 0;
        pFrame->GetWidth(imageWidth);    //imageWidth = 2752
        VmbUint32_t imageHeight = 0;
        pFrame->GetHeight(imageHeight);  //imageHeight = 2200

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////  Set Bitmap Settings   ////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //file header
        BITMAPFILEHEADER* bf = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
        bf->bfType              = 0x4d42;
        bf->bfSize              = imageSize + 40 + 14; //image size + infoheader size + fileheader size 
        bf->bfOffBits           = 54;

        //info header
        BITMAPINFOHEADER* bi = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;
        bi->biSize              = 40;
        bi->biWidth             = imageWidth;
        bi->biHeight            = imageHeight;
        bi->biPlanes            = 1;
        bi->biBitCount          = 24;
        bi->biCompression       = 0;
        bi->biSizeImage         = imageSize;
        bi->biXPelsPerMeter     = 2835;
        bi->biYPelsPerMeter     = 2835;
        bi->biClrUsed           = 0;
        bi->biClrImportant      = 0;


        //image data
        VmbUchar_t* imageData = new VmbUchar_t[imageSize];
        pFrame->GetImage(imageData);


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////  Output File to .bmp   ////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        std::ofstream outFile;

        outFile.open("test.bmp", std::ios::binary|std::ios::out);

        outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(bf), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
        outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(bi), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
        outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(imageData), imageSize);

        outFile.close();
```

Basically what is happening is that the data is properly being written to test.bmp, but test.bmp is still unopenable in a standard image viewer.  When I look at test.bmp in a hex editor, it appears everything is okay.  I know the imageData is working properly because when I crank up the light to maximum, the imageData is just a bunch of FF's (aka white) and when I turn the light off, every pixel of imageData is 00, 01, or 02. (aka black or near black). So the imageData portion of the file is being written properly. I can use their provided software to see the camera's images so I know the camera works fine (also this is what I used to make sure the light was bright enough to be a white screen and dark enough for a black screen). However, something must be wrong with either the fileheader or the infoheader (or both), and I cannot seem to figure out what it is.

Here is the Hex data of the file header and the info header:

```
42 4D 36 62 5C 00 CD CD CD CD 36 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 C0 
0D 0A 00 00 98 08 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 5C 
00 13 0B 00 00 13 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The imageSize, imageWidth, and imageHeight are the same (6054400, 2752, 2200 respectively) with each run, and the functions to get them are from the camera's API.  These work properly and simply return integers (at least from what I'm seeing in my autos).

Other info:
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

TL;DR:  What is wrong with my fileheader and/or infoheader?

Comment: The expression `std::ios::binary||std::ios::out` when opening the file is probably not what you want.

Comment: Well even if that is the case, I've written 2 or 3 test programs that wrote small bmp's using this code and they worked fine.  Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Then you probably used the _bitwise or_ operator `|` instead of the _logical or_ operator `||` when opening the file?

Comment: Oh yes that was just a copy/pasting error haha my bad but nonetheless is doesn't work with the bitwise operator included.

Comment: I would try and replace some of the magic numbers with sizeof() expressions or symbolic names, but that's a stylistic nitpick.  However, the header you're using doesn't match the header on wikipedia.  Also, you might want to check that the structs you're using are packed.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the two reserved fields in your File header.

File Header:
 4 bytes the size of the BMP file in bytes 
 2 bytes reserved; actual value depends on the application that creates the image 
 2 bytes reserved; actual value depends on the application that creates the image 
 4 bytes the offset, i.e. starting address, of the byte where the bitmap image data (pixel array) can be found.